# swift NPOSIXERRORDOMAIN warning about untanslocated node appears debugging anything under Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

if I just create a completely new hello world app in Xcode 13.2.1 - it all seems to work fine - I can do anything and this doesn't seem to be a problem beyond the noise, but my log fills up with many of these:

```
2022-02-20 10:14:44.073415+1100 helloworldproject[2387:3258621] [default] capability properties: could not find untranslocated node for <FSNode 0x600002cfe300> { isDir = ?, path = '/private/var/folders/x5/j8_s1gf110q3vwm00nfxd3lc0000gn/X/1129DA76-DFA0-5FEF-A3CB-319330C06433/d/Wrapper/helloworldproject.app' }, proceeding on the assumption it is not translocated: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"
```

I'm guessing it's some security setting that I haven't allowed or something - but it's happening every time I run with any project.  One thing is, I'm on an apple silicon box (m1 max) - last time I did any iOS dev I was on intel - and never got this, so wondering if it's an apple silicon thing?

bottom line - even though it doesn't seem to affect anything - is there any way of getting rid of it?

Comment: It seems as though you are missing a capability - maybe writetofile ?https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/iOS.Xcode.PBXProject.AddCapability.html